# Intersection between line and circle (tkz-euclide)

Tags: tikz-pgf

Now once, again I am trying to reconstruct one of these odd images in tikz.

[image: What I am trying to contstruct.]

Now, what is supposed to show, is only the triangle, the angle, and the line CD.
My attempt to do this is shown below

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvipsnames*,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(4,1){B}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzInterLC(A,B)(A,1pt) \tkzGetPoint{D}
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through D](A,D)
\tkzInterLC[R](D,tkzPointResult)(I,M) \tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawLinesegment(C,D)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I keep getting an error using this code. It has to do with the circle I am trying to create around A. Could anyone please help me, to spot and fix the mistake in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to specify the circle in `\tkzInterLC` using the center and the radius, you have to supply the `[R]` option. To get the intersection, use `\tkzGetFirstPoint` or `\tkzGetSecondPoint` as appropriate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(4,1){B}
\tkzDefMidPoint(A,B) \tkzGetPoint{M}
\tkzInterLC[R](A,B)(A,1cm) \tkzGetSecondPoint{D}
\tkzDefLine[orthogonal=through D](A,D)
\tkzInterLC(D,tkzPointResult)(M,A) \tkzGetSecondPoint{C}
\tkzDrawPolygon(A,B,C)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,D)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,D,M)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,D,M)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you are headache reliever!